# Are SimpleArrayMap and ArrayMap meant to retain order?

Tags: android, hashmap

I know the [`SimpleArrayMap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/SimpleArrayMap.html) and [`ArrayMap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/ArrayMap.html) classes are meant to be more efficient (for a small number of items) replacements for a `HashMap`. `HashMap` does not have a predictable iteration order (unlike `LinkedHashMap`), but I noticed a few methods within the `SimpleArrayMap` and `ArrayMap` classes that lead me to believe they might.

Methods like [`keyAt(int index)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/SimpleArrayMap.html#keyAt(int)), [`valueAt(int index)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/SimpleArrayMap.html#valueAt(int)) and [`removeAt(int index)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/SimpleArrayMap.html#removeAt(int)) seem to indicate that `SimpleArrayMap` and `ArrayMap` store their items in a predictable manner. These methods would also make it very convenient to access those items, so I added an `ArrayMap` to a `FragmentPagerAdapter` to hold the title and fragment for each page:

```
public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final ArrayMap<CharSequence, Fragment> mData = new ArrayMap();

    public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    public void addPage(CharSequence title, Fragment fragment) {
        mData.put(title, fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mData.keyAt(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mData.valueAt(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

}
```

Though I noticed in practice that the items returned by `getPageTitle()` and `getItem()` are not always in the order in which I added them to the `ArrayMap`. But why would these classes have methods that return keys and values by index (instead of just using the `Map#get(Object key)` method) if the indices of those items are not predictable?

Are `SimpleArrayMap` and `ArrayMap` meant to retain ordering? Am I doing something wrong? Or, if not, why would they contain the aforementioned methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the SimpleArrayMap implementation, it seems to grow and shrink dynamically when the put, putAll or remove methods are called. At that point your indexes may change. If you call [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) after your call to put, you will probably have a better time. Now this is just me reasoning about your code, so no guarantees. :)

Looking even closer at it, the indexOf method needs to search around the assumed index of an item, since the internal array of key-hash to index doesn't seem to be updated when shrinking the map. So indexes can apparently change.

```
int index = ContainerHelpers.binarySearch(mHashes, N, hash);

// If the hash code wasn't found, then we have no entry for this key.
if (index < 0) {
    return index;
}

// If the key at the returned index matches, that's what we want.
if (key.equals(mArray[index<<1])) {
   return index;
}

// Search for a matching key after the index.
int end;
for (end = index + 1; end < N && mHashes[end] == hash; end++) {
    if (key.equals(mArray[end << 1])) return end;
}

// Search for a matching key before the index.
for (int i = index - 1; i >= 0 && mHashes[i] == hash; i--) {
    if (key.equals(mArray[i << 1])) return i;
}

// Key not found -- return negative value indicating where a
// new entry for this key should go.  We use the end of the
// hash chain to reduce the number of array entries that will
// need to be copied when inserting.
return ~end;
```

The indexed methods probably exist for usages where you know that no modifications of the map has happened.

UPDATE:
In order for this to do what you want it to do, you need to implement 
`public long getItemId(int position)` as well, since your position doesn't give you a stable item id.

I would say that if you're expecting changes to the underlying map, then using the index-methods is probably not your best choice, since the cached indexes would have to be updated.

Comment: Calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` after calling `put()` would be smart. So far I have only added items before I set the adapter on the `ViewPager`, so this does not make a difference for my current code.

Comment: As for your reasoning, this seems extremely counter-intuitive. If they keys can change from the insertion-order, then calling `indexOfKey()` for every key after each insertion would be the only way of knowing which index belongs to each key-value pair. This seems to make retaining any indices utterly useless, essentially making `indexOfKey()` a middle-man for access to the value. Whereas the `get(Object key)` method can do so without such a middle-man.

Comment: Well, yes. If you make changes to the map, then you will need to rebuild your list of indexes. What I'm saying is that you're not guaranteed that the underlying array will retain ordering then. But if you already know that an object lives at a specific index, and the map hasn't changed, then you can use that index..

Comment: I am just trying to understand the point of having methods that reference an index if those indices are not predictable. If I call `put()` more than once, those indices are subject to change. This means that in order to use those index-based methods, I would have to retain my own list of indices. Then, in order to retain that list of indices, I would have to create a separate `Map` containing the keys and their matching indices, which entirely defeats the purpose of using an indexed `Map`…

Comment: @Bryan Well, not entirely. You might put a bunch of stuff into the map, and then when it is stable, for certain keys that you know you will look up often, you might call `indexOfValue(Object key)` once per such key, and then use that to return the elements directly, avoiding the cost of looking them up again. I agree that it's a little weird that they're exposed, but then Google code often is a little weird in my opinion.. In your case, I very much doubt that it is useful at all.